# Solving strict inequality nonlinear optimization problem in Matlab

Tags: optimization, matlab

I have a problem
$$ \min f(x) $$
$$s.a \quad x > l, \quad g(x) = 0 $$
where $f$ is a nonlinear function of $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $g$ is a vector function of $m$ nonlinear constraints.
I'm having trouble solving this on Matlab because fmincon seems to only be able to handle $\leq$ and not $>$. I'm aware I can work with $-x$ instead then solve and get the opposite of the solution so that the constraints become $<$ but they still remain strict...

Also, the nonlinear vector function doesn't seem to be working either... I read the syntax is fmincon(fun,x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,nonlcon), and the nonlcon should be a vector function of nonlinear constraints, but I wrote a function that yields the output $g(x)$ and called it, but it gives the error 'too many input arguments'...

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this type of problem not supported in matlab? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do you propose should be the solution to "minimize $x$ subject to $x>1$ (strictly)"?

Comment: It's not minimize $x$, it's $f(x)$..

Comment: I know, but consider $f(x)=x$ and please suggest what is the solution to the optimization problem I proposed.